# Create Pivot Table in Excel with 1 column per item

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel sheet with the following columns:

- Customer ID
- Date
- Purchase Status (values = success, fail, pending)

Maximum number of rows with the same Customer ID is 4

I'd like to turn it into a table (pivot table?) where I have 5 columns:

- Customer ID
- Purchase 1
- Purchase 2
- Purchase 3
- Purchase 4

That table should have 1 row per customer ID

Purchase 1 Column should show the purchase status for the customer's first purchase (based on earliest date from the Date column)

Purchase 2 column should show the purchase status for the customer's second purchase, etc.

If the customer only had 2 purchases, then only Purchase 1 and Purchase 2 columns should be populated.

So my table would look something like this:

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu4PI.png)

Would really appreciate any help on how to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to do this...

**Data**

[image]

Click on Insert -> Pivot Table, select table range and where you want the data to go  and select the check box - *Add this data to data model*

You will see the Range in the pivot table field above all the column names -> Right click and select Add Measure.

This will open a new window. Add the Measure Name (PassFailPending in screen shot below)

In the formula section, add `=CONCATENATEX(Range,[Purchase Status],", ")`

Click on Check DAX formula to make sure the formula is good

[image]

Drag the various columns as you would normally create your pivot table as in screen shot below with the formula as the values...

[image]

This will create the table. As the totals don't look good, you can ...
Go To Design Tab > Select Grand Totals > Off for rows and columns

[image]

This will given below output

[image]